# Is there a spice that is hot and colorless?

Tags: drinks, chili-peppers, spicy-hot

I want to prepare a drink that is hot (spicy) but I don't want to use regular hot sauce because it will affect the color. Is there anything like "clear" hot sauce?

Comment: I assume this is for the purposes of some sort of practical joke.

Comment: No, I just want to spice up a drink without affecting it's color.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let a hot pepper (jalapeño or habañero, perhaps) soak in your liquid for however long it takes to achieve the desired hotness.

Comment: It worked very well. All I had was a long green pepper (not very hot). I perforated it and soaked it in vodka for 6 hours. The vodka got quite hot. There is a noticeable smell and taste of green pepper though.

Comment: Most of the capsaicin is in the seeds and pith (white stuff inside the pepper). You could try just soaking those parts. They might not have as much pepper flavor.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, I'd look for pure Capsaicin if all you want is the heat. It's colorless/odorless so could work, but I'm not sure where you can find it.

I've heard of white, hot sauces which may work for you, here is [an example](http://www.onlyhotsauce.com/1777-frostbite-hot-sauce.html)

Comment: The vinegar (and possibly the salt) in the sauce you linked to might make it a bad call for drinks, but good thought!

Comment: @Jefromi: Depends on the drink.  Tobasco is regularly used in drinks and that has a substantial amount of vinegar and some salt.

Comment: A note regarding capsaicin: pure crystalized capsaicin is _ridiculously_ hot. I can't stress enough how intolerably mind blowing it is. A spec the size of one of the commas in your answer in a can of tomato soup renders it inedible. I have a very high tolerance for capsaicin too.

Comment: As @hobodave hints at, pure capsaicin is 15-16 *million* on the [Scoville Scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoville_scale), which is over 10 times hotter than the infamous "ghost chili".  If you actually manage to get hold of it, don't even try to measure it out directly; you need to dilute it first.

Comment: The brand 'Pure Cap' comes in a dropped bottle inside a child-proof container.  I've seen people dip a tooth pick into a drop of it, then touch it to their tounge and decide it was too much.

Answer (score 4):

Szechuan (Sichuan) pepper husks can be brewed/simmered in hot water and results in a relatively clear broth that can be very "hot" and a much more interesting taste than refined or artificial capsaicin

It also has that numbing effect that most people find rather interesting

Answer (score 4):

[Cajohn's Frostbite](https://www.cajohns.com/store/Frostbite-White-Hot-Sauce) it is a clear hot sauce and pretty good for making mixed drinks

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a link. It looks interesting! The reviews on the page suggest that it's a pretty good product and might be ideal for the OP's purpose so I upvoted too. Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Answer (score 1):

I have some habanero powder that has a beige color.  I would imagine that wouldn't discolor a clear liquid too much.  And believe me, a little bit goes a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Fresh uncooked Ginger paste has quite a kick to it, as does fresh ground Horseradish.
The tastes are not much like capsicum, but can be eye-wateringly potent.

Answer (score 0):

There's a style of hot sauce that is basically whole peppers soaking in a vinegar solution; it's probably work, but it'd give a sour note from the vinegar.

You could always make your own ... it tends to be made with green peppers; I'm guessing green or yellow would impart less color.

Also, a quick search suggests that there's at least two brands of 'clear hotsauce' out there -- Panola and Frostbite.